# Android constraintLayout shifts all the childs to the top

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_arrow_back"
    style="@style/BackArrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:text="@string/speed_test"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_arrow_back"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_arrow_back" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_flag"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_usa"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_title" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_country_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
    android:text="USA"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_flag" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
    android:text="New York"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/background_white_circle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_country_name" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/background_main_connected"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/background_white_circle"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_white_circle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_city" />

  <com.sharkvpn.avantize.views.speedometer.TubeSpeedometer
    android:id="@+id/tubeSpeedometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_white_circle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background_white_circle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background_white_circle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background_white_circle"
    app:sv_indicator="NeedleIndicator"
    app:sv_indicatorColor="?attr/accent_color"
    app:sv_indicatorWidth="5dp"
    app:sv_markHeight="12dp"
    app:sv_markWidth="1dp"
    app:sv_marksNumber="40"
    app:sv_maxSpeed="300"
    app:sv_speedTextColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:sv_speedometerBackColor="@color/light_gray"
    app:sv_speedometerWidth="30dp"
    app:sv_tickNumber="9"
    app:sv_tickTextFormat="INTEGER"
    app:sv_unitTextColor="@android:color/transparent" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_signal_strength"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_connection_strong"
    android:translationZ="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_ping"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt_ping"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_ping" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_ping"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
    android:text="26 ms"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:translationZ="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tubeSpeedometer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tubeSpeedometer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tubeSpeedometer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tubeSpeedometer" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_speed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
    android:text="5,17"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txt_ping"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_ping"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_ping" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_mbps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
    android:text="@string/format_mbps"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txt_speed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_speed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_speed" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_limited_speed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
    android:text="@string/limited_speed"
    android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_mbps" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/download_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_download"
      android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_download" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_download"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text="@string/download"
      android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_download_speed"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
      android:text="5,17"
      android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
      android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_download_mbps"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text="@string/format_mbps"
      android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
      android:textSize="16sp" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/upload_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_upload"
      android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_upload"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text="@string/upload"
      android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_upload_speed"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
      android:text="0,00"
      android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
      android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_upload_mbps"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text="@string/format_mbps"
      android:textColor="?attr/accent_color"
      android:textSize="16sp" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_limited_speed" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_features"
    style="@style/HintTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/features"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/features_layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/features_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/upgrade_layout">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_pro"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_pro_inactive"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_map"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_map_point"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/upgrade_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_pro"
    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_upgrade_to"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
      android:text="@string/upgrade_to_no_trim"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_pro"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text="@string/pro"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_upgrade_to"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_unlock"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text="@string/unlock"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_upgrade_to" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_all_services"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
      android:text="@string/all_services"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_unlock"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_upgrade_to" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_free_trial"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
      android:text="@string/_3_days_free_trial"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/txt_pro"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_monthly"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/txt_pro" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_monthly"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
      android:text="@string/_9_99usd_monthly"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/txt_unlock"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/txt_unlock" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The first screen is the Android Studio preview, the second one is the actual emulator result. For a reason, it shifts all the elements at the top of the layout,
The first screen is the Android Studio preview, the second one is the actual emulator result. For a reason, it shifts all the elements at the top of the layout
The first screen is the Android Studio preview, the second one is the actual emulator result. For a reason, it shifts all the elements at the top of the layout
The first screen is the Android Studio preview, the second one is the actual emulator result. For a reason, it shifts all the elements at the top of the layout
The first screen is the Android Studio preview, the second one is the actual emulator result. For a reason, it shifts all the elements at the top of the layout

[image: Android studio preview]

[image: Actual emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was wrap_content for FragmentContainerView in activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Some vertical constraints are missing in your layout.

All your views need to have these 2 constraints on each other:

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottom|TopOf="id|parent"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottom|TopOf="id|parent"
```

You can start with the elements in the bottom:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_features"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/features_layout"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_features"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/upgrade_layout">
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/upgrade_layout"
        ...   
        // no changes : this element needs to be in the bottom
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

and keep going up in the layout to add vertical constraints.